# Проблемы с attach in WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Добрый день, решил прикрепить процесс cmd к panel, но на Win7 возникла проблема он не правильно подгоняет ширину встраиваемого cmd, хотя этот же код прекрасно работает на win8

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

Eventlogging = "Модуль Командная строка: инициализация запуска cmd";
ValueCommandLine.StatusRunCmd = true;
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = "cd c:\\";
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = Info;
p.Start();
MainForm.ValueCommandLine.ProcessCmdID = p.Id;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
IntPtr hostHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
ValueCommandLine.ProcessHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
SetParent(hostHandle, panel6.Handle);
SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, panel6.Location.X - 20, panel6.Location.Y - 68, panel6.Size.Width + 20, panel6.Size.Height + 40, 0x0040);

private void panel6_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowPos(ValueCommandLine.ProcessHandle, 0, panel6.Location.X - 20, panel6.Location.Y - 68, panel6.Size.Width + 20, panel6.Size.Height + 40, 0x0040);
}
```

> Да еще вопрос, при попытки изменить размер основной формы, он делает
>   это очень медленно, рывками.

*Как решить эти две проблемы.*

Answer (score 2):

Размеры консоли должны быть кратны ширине символов - возможно, дело в этом, поскольку в Win7 и в Win8 ширина границ окна различается.

А вообще, по-моему было бы правильнее запускать невидимую консоль с перенаправлением ввода-вывода и реализовать для неё интерфейс самостоятельно.